# How to cluster the SURF keypoints in matlab using kmeans algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I want to do the comparison between the query image and my trained image to retrieve the similar images in my data set.
so that i extract the SURF features for my trained image and save it as(.mat) file in a folder then my next step is to cluster the similar features and find the distance to retrieve the target image.

please give some idea to cluster the surf points using k-means cluster algorithm..